# Provisioning profile has beta-reports-active but I still get iTunes Connect TestFlight warning

Tags: jenkins, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, testflight

I can successfully upload to iTunesConnect Test Flight from my Xcode but I'm failing to to set it up as a Jenkins job.

I get the error on iTunes Connect

```
To use TestFlight Beta Testing, build xxx must contain the correct beta entitlement.
```

I can verify that the .ipa created in Jenkins does have `beta-reports-active` under `Entitlements`.

But I'm still getting the error from iTunes Connect Test Flight which prevent us from testing the app.

I am using my AppStore provisioning profile. I'm not sure yet whether this is correct but it's the only one that had the beta-reports-active under Entitlements so I'm using that.

**Related question:** Can i upload to iTunes Connect Test Flight with other provisioning profile (such as dev?)

Comment: Did you find a solution to make this warning go away? We are struggling with the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: @hybridcattt we went with HockeyApp in the end, so I haven't tried to figure this one out any further at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Without quoting the error, how do you expect people to help you?

For your other question: in order to upload to iTC, you need an AppStore provisioning profile, even for the "beta"

Comment: The error states that my build didn't contain the correct beta entitlement. Regarding the AppStore provisioning profile, I was afraid that was the case. Thanks.